# 3D Printer only printing half of an object

Tags: ultimaker-cura

My 3D printer is only printing half of the object I want to print. I have a WANHAO i3 Mini and i use Cura, I've added some images below that shows the problem:

[image]

**I entered this values as Settings:**
[image: I entered this values as Settings]

**Final Object:**
[image: Final Object]

Comment: Just a note, does the Duplicator mini use 2.85 mm filament? It says so in your settings. On topic: this is a peculiar issue, never seen this before in years of printing, I have no clue. If you load the G-code file back in Cura or an online G-code visualization tool, how does the virtual print look?

Comment: I'm guessing it involves an STL file with half the triangles reversed, probably because someone designed half of the object then mirrored everyting *as STL* (including the triangle orientations) to make the other half. The solution is going to be either going back to create a proper/valid STL file or using one of the many mesh fixer utilities available.

Comment: please preview the movement paths. I agree with R.. that there might be an isssue with the STL